# How to ignore HTML tags on download in tabulator?

Tags: html, download, tags, xlsx, tabulator

gettting HTML tags even when i use formatter: function (cell, formatterParams, onRendered) { return cell.getValue(); } in tabulator.

How to ignore HTML tags on download in tabulator.

unable to ignore htm tags currently